# How could we found BULK INSERT completion percentage in SQL server using C#?

Tags: sql-server

How could we found BULK INSERT completion percentage in SQL server using C#?

I have tried with the following query:

```
SELECT d.name databasename,
      r.command,
      r.percent_complete,
      r.session_id,
      r.start_time,
      estimated_finish_time = DATEADD(MILLISECOND,estimated_completion_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r INNER JOIN  sys.databases d ON r.database_id = d.database_id WHERE r.command like '%BULK INSERT%'
```

But I am unable to get the result as per the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The percent complete is only available for few [selected commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx).

```
ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE
AUTO_SHRINK option with ALTER DATABASE
BACKUP DATABASE
DBCC CHECKDB
DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP
DBCC CHECKTABLE
DBCC INDEXDEFRAG
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE
DBCC SHRINKFILE
RECOVERY
RESTORE DATABASE,
ROLLBACK
TDE ENCRYPTION
```

Comment: Hi Jamesz, Thanks for reply!!! I have also found such things using URL : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx
Do we have any other way to fullfill our requirenment ? Thanks in advance

Comment: If your target table is empty at the start, or you know how many rows there were, running `select count(*)` with transaction isolation level read uncommitted might help. Haven't tried it with bulk insert.